# network UNCLAIMED with new net card (22.04.1)

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, intel

I installed a new Intel X540 10g network card in my Ubuntu 22.04.1 pc, but I'm struggling to get it working (built in 1gbps ethernet ports are working). lshw shows network UNCLAIMED - anyone have any insights on what I did wrong or what I can do to get it going?  Details below, thanks!

**lshw -class network**:

```
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:49:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f8700000-f877ffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:49:00.1
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f8780000-f87fffff
```

**lspci | grep -i ether**:

```
44:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
45:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
49:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
49:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list**:

```
44:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
        DeviceName: Onboard LAN RTL8111
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c60]
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
45:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c60]
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
46:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP [1022:1485]
```

I did try to install the driver from Intel:
**lsmod | grep ixgb**:

```
ixgbe                 417792  0
dca                    16384  2 igb,ixgbe
```

**modinfo ixgbe**:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko
version:        5.18.6
license:        GPL
description:    Intel(R) 10GbE PCI Express Linux Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     2C6DB0ACD63753C204814B9
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015CCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015CAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015AEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ADsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ACsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015ABsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015B0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015AAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015D1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001563sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001560sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001558sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001557sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000154Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001528sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000151Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001529sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000152Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001514sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001507sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010FBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001517sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010FCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001508sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010ECsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000150Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        dca
retpoline:      Y
name:           ixgbe
vermagic:       5.15.0-56-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           IntMode:Change Interrupt Mode (0=Legacy, 1=MSI, 2=MSI-X), default 2 (array of int)
parm:           InterruptType:Change Interrupt Mode (0=Legacy, 1=MSI, 2=MSI-X), default IntMode (deprecated) (array of int)
parm:           MQ:Disable or enable Multiple Queues, default 1 (array of int)
parm:           DCA:Disable or enable Direct Cache Access, 0=disabled, 1=descriptor only, 2=descriptor and data (array of int)
parm:           RSS:Number of Receive-Side Scaling Descriptor Queues, default 0=number of cpus (array of int)
parm:           VMDQ:Number of Virtual Machine Device Queues: 0/1 = disable (1 queue) 2-16 enable (default=8) (array of int)
parm:           max_vfs:Number of Virtual Functions: 0 = disable (default), 1-63 = enable this many VFs (array of int)
parm:           VEPA:VEPA Bridge Mode: 0 = VEB (default), 1 = VEPA (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Maximum interrupts per second, per vector, (0,1,956-488281), default 1 (array of int)
parm:           LLIPort:Low Latency Interrupt TCP Port (0-65535) (array of int)
parm:           LLIPush:Low Latency Interrupt on TCP Push flag (0,1) (array of int)
parm:           LLISize:Low Latency Interrupt on Packet Size (0-1500) (array of int)
parm:           LLIEType:Low Latency Interrupt Ethernet Protocol Type (array of int)
parm:           LLIVLANP:Low Latency Interrupt on VLAN priority threshold (array of int)
parm:           FdirPballoc:Flow Director packet buffer allocation level:
                        1 = 8k hash filters or 2k perfect filters
                        2 = 16k hash filters or 4k perfect filters
                        3 = 32k hash filters or 8k perfect filters (array of int)
parm:           AtrSampleRate:Software ATR Tx packet sample rate (array of int)
parm:           FCoE:Disable or enable FCoE Offload, default 1 (array of int)
parm:           MDD:Malicious Driver Detection: (0,1), default 1 = on (array of int)
parm:           LRO:Large Receive Offload (0,1), default 0 = off (array of int)
parm:           allow_unsupported_sfp:Allow unsupported and untested SFP+ modules on 82599 based adapters, default 0 = Disable (array of int)
parm:           dmac_watchdog:DMA coalescing watchdog in microseconds (0,41-10000), default 0 = off (array of int)
parm:           vxlan_rx:VXLAN receive checksum offload (0,1), default 1 = Enable (array of int)
```

[EDIT adding requested output]

**lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3**

```
44:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
        DeviceName: Onboard LAN RTL8111
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c60]
        Kernel driver in use: igb
--
45:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c60]
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
--
49:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [8086:1528] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [1dcf:031b]
        Kernel modules: ixgbe
49:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [8086:1528] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [1dcf:031b]
        Kernel modules: ixgbe
4a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
```

**sudo modprobe ixgbe && sudo dmesg | grep ixgbe**

```
[    0.997958] ixgbe: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    0.998081] ixgbe: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    0.999798] ixgbe: probe of 0000:49:00.0 failed with error -5
[    0.999875] ixgbe: probe of 0000:49:00.1 failed with error -5
```

Comment: May we also see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sure! Edited the original post and added that output.

Comment: Let's also see: `sudo modprobe ixgbe && sudo dmesg | grep ixgbe`

Comment: Now that one is promising! 
`[    0.997958] ixgbe: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.

[    0.998081] ixgbe: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

[    0.999798] ixgbe: probe of 0000:49:00.0 failed with error -5

[    0.999875] ixgbe: probe of 0000:49:00.1 failed with error -5`

I built the driver by downloading the tar from the intel website and doing a **make install**, but the readme didn't say anything about a X.509 certificate.

Comment: deactivate for test secure boot in uefi

Comment: Yes, indeed. Turn off Secure Boot in the BIOS/UEFI, reboot and show again: `sudo dmesg | grep ixgbe` If this is a dual boot with Windows, also disable Fast Boot.

Comment: Hmm. BIOS reports secure boot is already disabled (as is AMD "trusted computing platform"), and it is a dedicated ubuntu server, no windows dual boot. dmesg is unchanged after reboot.

Comment: I notice that *ixgbe* is already included in kernel version 5.15.0-xx. Why did you build a newer (??) version from source? Did you also have the probe failed problem? Are there any settings in the BIOS related to the 10 gb devices?

Comment: The card didn't show up on first boot after I installed it, so I assumed it needed a driver and downloaded it from intel. My linux hardware skillset is not high -- I'm happy to use the "inbox" driver if it is easier to get that working. No BIOS settings related to 10gb/pcie network cards -- only options are to disable the 2 onboard nics.

Comment: at some point the version in the kernel broke essentially. I don't know what's the 'last' version that worked, but it seems a widespread problem in debian derivatives. Its still an issue in 2024 ... ._.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot seems to be good instructions on signing but I couldn't get it to work since apparently the box I was running it on was in CSM mode, and remote. Solution in answers

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You need a 6.x kernel, and HWE kernels on 22.04 include it.

I had the same issue on a system running a X553 chipset. Interestingly the gigabit ports on the chip were fine, but the 10 gig ports vanished. For extra fun they worked when I initially set it up, then stopped after an update.

Short version is that there's a bug in the version of the ixgbe driver in kernel with 5.10. I *think* some older versions are not affected. You need a 6.x kernel - and it'll definately works.

Trying to build a kernel module failed, mostly due to past me's mistakes, but *should* work. You will need to sign it - there seem to be logical instructions on [ubuntu's blog](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot), but my machine's remote, currenly on CSM, and you need to enable secureboot and add your own key. However, the 6.x kernels seem to have fixed it, and installing it will get you a working *in kernel driver* with minimal faff.

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` will install a newer kernel

5.15.0-101-generic was the current, non HWE kernel at the time of this post, and the 10 gig ports on my system didn't work.  6.5.0-26-generic is the HWE kernel - and includes working ixgbe drivers. I kind of figured out it was a issue with this kernel series from the comments to this [serve at home post](https://www.servethehome.com/intel-x553-networking-and-proxmox-ve-8-1-3/), and the comments narrowed it down to a [specific commit](https://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&m=170113799914642)